# Enviar texto através de input pulsando 1 de los 2 botones

Tags: php, html

Buenas, estoy haciendo un pequeño ejercicio en php en el cual tengo un html donde envío un texto cualquiera y pulsar uno de los dos botones, tengo un archivo php que recogerá la información y la visualizara pero no se me ocurre como hacerlo.
Por ejemplo pongo en el html la palabra hola y pulso el botón 1, pues el php lo recogerá y visualizara "has enviado el texto hola pulsando el botón 1"

Código html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dos botones</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Enviar texto pulsando 1 de los 2 botones</h2>
        <form method="get" action="comprobar.php">
            <label>Escribe aqui:</label>
            <input type="text" name="texto">
            <input type="submit" name="botones[]" value="boton1"/>
            <input type="submit" name="botones[]" value="boton2"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código php hasta ahora:

```
<?php

    $texto = $_GET["texto"];
    $botones = $_GET["botones"];

    foreach($botones as $boton)
    {

    }
    echo "Has enviado el texto ".$texto. "pulsando el botón ".$boton;
?>
```

Mi intención era recorrer los botones y sacar el que se haya pulsado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quita el foreach.. solo coloca esto:

```
echo "Has enviado el texto ".$texto. "pulsando el botón ".$botones[0];
```

> al presionar el boton 1 o el boton 2, solo se envia el valor de 1 solo botón, y es con el que presionas. Esto lo puedes corroborar con un `var_dump($_GET)` o un `print_r($_GET)`.

Si en tu html solo usas `name="boton"`, basta con usar `$_GET['boton]` y te retornará el valor del boton al que le diste click, y no los 2. y pasa lo mismo con tu codigo, siempre se envia solo 1, solo que me tido en un array. Usar `name="boton"` en los 2 `inputs` no causará problema

Comment: Gracias amigo me sirvió :D